# How do i insert an array of input fields into mysql with php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to insert an array of dynamically generated input field into my db.
The problem is that the insertion gets messed up during insertion. Some records get inserted into the wrong Rows when Some field in the form are left empty.
I red somewhere that i have to index my arrays properly. i don't know how to do this. Is there a better way of doing this? or is there a way of fixing my code.

I have searched everywhere for help and i haven't found any. I would really appreciate it if i could get some help from the experts here.

Here is the form

```
                        <?php
                        while($row2=$coursefetch1->fetch()){


                          $iid = $row2['id'];
                          if($row2['type'] == 0){
                          echo '

                            <div class="tab-pane" id="'.$row2['id'].'">
                              <div class="row" align="center">

                              <b> '.$row2['question'].' </b><br>
                              <input type="hidden" name="question[]" value="'.$row2['question'].'">

                              <input type="hidden" name="test_id[]" value="'.$row2['test_id'].'">
                              <input type="checkbox" name="yanswer1[]" value="a"><span> '.$row2['a'].' </span><br>
                              <input type="checkbox" name="yanswer2[]" value="b"><span> '.$row2['b'].' </span><br>
                              <input type="checkbox" name="yanswer3[]" value="c"><span> '.$row2['c'].' </span><br>
                              <input type="checkbox" name="yanswer4[]" value="d"><span> '.$row2['d'].' </span><br>


                              </div>
                            </div>

                        ';
                      }


                      elseif($row2['type'] == 2){
                      echo '

                        <div class="tab-pane" id="'.$row2['id'].'">
                          <div class="row" align="center">

                          <b> '.$row2['question'].' </b><br>
                          <input type="hidden" name="question[]" value="'.$row2['question'].'">

                          <input type="hidden" name="test_id[]" value="'.$row2['test_id'].'">
                          <input type="radio" name="yanswer1[]" value="a"><span> '.$row2['a'].' </span><br>
                          <input type="radio" name="yanswer2[]" value="b"><span> '.$row2['b'].' </span><br>
                          <input type="radio" name="yanswer3[]" value="c"><span> '.$row2['c'].' </span><br>
                          <input type="radio" name="yanswer4[]" value="d"><span> '.$row2['d'].' </span><br>


                          </div>
                        </div>

                    ';
                  }

                          elseif($row2['type'] == 1){

                            echo '

                            <div class="tab-pane" id="'.$row2['id'].'">
                              <div class="row" align="center">

                              <b> '.$row2['question'].' </b><br>
                              <input type="hidden" name="question[]" value="'.$row2['question'].'">

                              <input type="hidden" name="test_id[]" value="'.$row2['test_id'].'">
                              <input type="text" name="yanswer1[]" value="">


                              </div>
                            </div>


                            ';




                          }
                        }



                        ?>
```

Here is the file that processes the form

```
                    <?php
                    require "head.php";


                    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                      $question_array = $_POST['question'];
                      $testid_array = $_POST['test_id'];
                      $answer_array1 = $_POST['yanswer1'];
                      $answer_array2 = $_POST['yanswer2'];
                      $answer_array3 = $_POST['yanswer3'];
                      $answer_array4 = $_POST['yanswer4'];
                      $i = 0;
                    for($i = 0; $i < count($question_array); $i++) {
                        $question = $question_array[$i];
                        $testid = $testid_array[$i];
                        $answer = $answer_array1[$i]."".$answer_array2[$i]."".$answer_array3[$i]."".$answer_array4[$i];

                        $enterscore = $achilles->prepare("INSERT INTO `user_answer` (test_id,question,your_answer)
                        VALUES (:t,:q,:a)");

                        $enterscore->bindparam(':t',$testid);
                        $enterscore->bindparam(':q',$question);
                        $enterscore->bindparam(':a',$answer);
                        $enterscore->execute();

                      }
                    }

                    ?>
```

Comment: what do you mean by array of input. Could you show us the sample input and expected output ?

Comment: I have an array of checkbox, radio and text fields in a html form and i am trying to insert tha values in the array into db

Answer (score 0):

...

```
<input type="hidden" name="test_id" value="'.$row2['test_id'].'">
<input type="radio" name="yanswer1" value="a"><span> '.$row2['a'].' </span><br>
<input type="radio" name="yanswer2" value="b"><span> '.$row2['b'].' </span><br>
<input type="radio" name="yanswer3" value="c"><span> '.$row2['c'].' </span><br>
```

...
in other places by analogy

edit: 
...

```
if (!empty($_POST['submit'])) {
```

...